# How to create multiple callbacks using a double for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash

Scenario
I have a pool of x container div, each containing y number of input fields which are all hidden.

And I have the below form which contains a single input field (which takes a number n) and a submit button.

On a single click, based on the input a Div container is created with the n number of input fields (which were initially hidden). This will require an x number of callbacks functions which will be invoked later to grab values. Now on each click based on whatever n is provided, another container is created with a set of new input fields. This can be done up to some limit based on the preset size of the hidden division created in the first place.

The problem is that I have lots of similar-looking callbacks, which I thought be better to put in a loop, in this case, a double for loop. One for each container, and one for each new element inside that container. But it's not working, but using a single for loop for creating each element (callbacks) inside a container is working fine. If I put that in a double for loop it doesn't seem to work.

```
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        @app.callback(Output(f'{i}-{j}','children'),[Input(...)])
        def foo(value):
            pass
```

I want to know is that even possible to do so with Dash? Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do with these callback functions?  Do you need to return them to some caller to invoke later, or do you want to call them immediately?

Comment: In Dash, you can modify multiple Outputs using the same Input in just one call

Comment: Aditionally, your 'i-j' string is not being formatted with the for loops input

Comment: Updated questions with more details

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to create an array of callbacks to do something with later, you could do it like this:

```
[app.callback(Output('i-j', 'children'), [Input(...)])(lambda value: None) for j in range(5) for i in range(5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of use case, i would recommend [Pattern-Matching Callbacks](https://dash.plotly.com/pattern-matching-callbacks).